# Meaning of '^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$'

Tags: python, regex, django

```
# urls.py
site_media = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
                                     {'document_root': site_media}),
)
```

I have problems to understand the meaning of the expression used in above statement.

```
'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$'
```

What does it really mean?

Thank you

// ========== Updated based on comments  ==============

Reference: [Name Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

In Python regular expressions, the syntax for named regular-expression 
groups is `(?P<name>pattern)`, where **name** is the name of the group and 
**pattern** is some pattern to match.

Comparison:

**Method 1>**

```
(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
```

A request to `/articles/2005/03/` would call the function

`news.views.month_archive(request, year='2005', month='03')`,

**Method 2>**

```
(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
```

A request to `/articles/2005/03/` would call the function

`news.views.month_archive(request, '2005', '03')`.

Comment: Have you had a chance to go through the tutorial yet?

Comment: Also, do you understand regular expressions? If not, now is the time to learn about them. http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @Jordan, I know RE but I have problems to understand `(?P<path>.*)`.

Comment: see named groups https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: Oh, `?P` just means "a named RE group is coming up" and `<path>` means the name of the group is `path`. So after pattern matching, the `.*` part is available in kwargs with the name `path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

urls are pretty well explained in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 2):

`(?P<path>.*)` is a named group. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html